# Module not found in -Swift.h file generated at Objective-C top app level for a Swift framework with dependencies

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks, dependencies

I have an Objective-C app, A, which embeds a Swift framework, B, which in turn has an Objective-C framework dependency, C.

When a Swift class from framework B subclasses an Objective-C class from framework C, the A-Swift.h file generated when A is run gives the compile-time error

> 'Module 'C' not found'

If framework C is added separately to app A, app A compiles but crashes with the following error at runtime -

> Class SomeClass is implemented in both..

Is there a way for a Swift class from B to subclass a class from C and have A run successfully?

NOTE:

Framework B has been manually added to app A in Embedded Binaries.

Framework C was added to B both via Cocoapods and manually via Embedded Binaries

EXAMPLE:

See ObjCSampleApp (Pods for C into B) and ObjCSampleManualApp in the following repo https://github.com/bryanboyko/SwiftObjCIntegration

Comment: Is there some cocoa pods involved in this ?

Comment: (Added edit) I tried integrating C into B both manually and via Cocoapods